# get request parameter from url in HP loadrunner

Tags: automated-tests, loadrunner

I am using HP loadrunner for my automatic tests. 
Every time, when i run my application, it creates some transfer and also generates id in URL. 
How can i get the id from URL?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `web_reg_save_param` function in LoadRunner is used for this. The following line will save the current page URL to the parameter (URL).

```
web_reg_save_param("URL", "LB/ic=Location: ", "RB=\r\n", "Search=Headers", LAST);
```

If you know what the ID is that your looking for, ie. http://www.example.com/?id=298374293847 you can adjust the call accordingly.

```
web_reg_save_param("URL", "LB/ic=Location: http://www.example.com/?id=", "RB=\r\n", "Search=Headers", LAST);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also check out web_reg_save_param_ex() and web_reg_save_param_regexp()- Similar but provide a little more options for capturing data

Answer (score 1):

Recording with Siebel 8.1 on [Loadrunner 11](http://forum.360logica.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=954) having issues,posted a question on HP and got the same comment. But usually we can try the below mentioned option

1. You can record in Siebel-Web or web (http/html) and playback as
   either too (if you want to record in Siebel-Web and play back in
   regular web, just copy the contents of the script to a regular web
   script and save).
2. Try a proxy mode recording in LR.
3. Changing registry and disables NTLM.
4. Turn off all autocorrelation rules
5. Turn on record as URL mode (as an alternate use web_custom_requests())
6. Use a sniffer to capture the traffic and then build a script by hand.(Best Option)
7. Change settings on the Siebel server side as well (Enable Automation=True, EnableWebClientAutomation = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

If you are recording your scripts using Web http/html you can use automatic correlation. For automatic correlation go to Design Studio
If you are unable to find the value there,then you must correlate manually using **web_reg_save_param** by giving the left and right boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

This is going to sound belligerent, condescending and downright offensive.    It is not to be meant as a reflection on you, but upon your management who has placed you in this position.

The topic of Correlation is one covered extensively in the class for LoadRunner web script development.   It is the topic of a full 1/3 of the class and an additional appendix.   All told some four different techniques for collecting dynamic data are covered, presented or documented as a part of the class materials.   This capability, the handling of dynamic data, is a foundation tool skill.

Vardges, your management has placed you in a tough spot.   Personally I would bolt for greener fields, for any management which is willing to do this to a line-of-business employee is also willing to toss that same person under the bus to salvage their own hide or a client relationship.   Blaming you for something that management is unwilling to address is not a question of "if?" when training and mentoring does not occur, but only "when?" will the blame be placed on you.

James Pulley

Moderator: YahooGroups Advanced-LoadRunner, YahooGroups LoadRunner, SQAForums LoadRunner, LinkedIn LoadRunner, GoogleGroups lr-loadrunner